# Do a question's (answer's) score affect its rankings in seach engines' results?

Tags: discussion, google, score

Typically, top SO-related results in Google search are highly upvoted questions (answers). It rarely happens to me to land on a question with negative score. I wonder if scores somehow affect the questions' rankings or it's only content that matters.

Comment: Since we are not Google, or other search engine, any answer would be speculation. One can also speculate that the questions that appear on top in search results get more traffic, and subsequently more votes.